# How to use $\chi^2$ test to test if my data follow a $\chi^2$ distribution?

Tags: chi-squared-test

How to use $\chi^2$ test to test if my data follow a $\chi^2$ distribution with a fixed degrees of freedom? or is there any way to do it with Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB there's `chi2gof` function, you can supply ['CDF' argument](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html#namevaluepairarguments) to specify the distribution. By default it's Normal, but you can plug many more [available in MATLA](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html#inputarg_distname)B including $\chi^2$ itself.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really want to use a $\chi^2$ test for this, since that would require you to needlessly and arbitrarily bin your data. You want to do a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test. The KS test takes as input a data sample and a distribution and produces as output a test statistic D with a known distribution under the null hypothesis that your data are drawn from the given distribution. The test is non-parametric in the sense that the distribution of D is independent of the distribution of data.